# How to get the google play store locale

Tags: android, google-play-services

I know that google play store determines its location by IP address, account information. but is there a way of getting the locale that the google play store is using?

Answer (score 2):

If you're fetching in-app purchasables from the Google Play store, they will have a price_currency_code that is the "ISO 4217 currency code for price. For example, if price is specified in British pounds sterling, price_currency_code is "GBP"."

I don't think there is a way to get this information without querying Google Play for available products (and returning at least one product).

More info available on [Google's API documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails).

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean the locale of the play store? as most of the apps the locale is read through the System locale value that is set for the actual device.

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Comment: I was trying to get the currency used when user purchase using in app billing. Since there's no way for me to get the currency code like USD or CNY from the getSkuDetails from In-app-billing v3, i was thinking if i can get the locale used by the google play store, i can get the currency code by using Currency.getInstance(locale)

Comment: Well you have the locale now. But it is impossible to show the actual real price in anything else than USD, so you should show it in USD and have approximate price in whatever currency you think the user wants to see (12$ aprox. 8 eur) there will be conversion rates and stuff affecting the final price.